# Regression using aggregate (averaged) data

Tags: regression, ancova, aggregation

I'm doing a project involving the impact that different college grading systems have on MCAT performance. I have access to the following data:

1. Grading system by college
2. Median MCAT score by college
3. Number of students taking the MCAT by college
4. Median SAT score (among pre-meds) by college

I would like to regress median MCAT score on (1) median SAT score and (2) grading system (using a dummy variable = 0 or 1).

Could someone tell me if this is a statistically valid (or at least defensible) analysis to do? I have read about some of the pitfalls of regressions with aggregate data (ecological fallacy, etc.). Unfortunately, I don't have access to the individual SAT or MCAT scores (I only have the median scores for each college), so this seems like the best I can do. Is there anything I can do to make the analysis more defensible?

Comment: Can you obtain some measure of *variability* of the scores within each college, such as the quartiles?  That would open up many more options.

Comment: How many colleges are there in your data?

Comment: @whuber For my purposes, I think it's reasonable to assume that the standard deviations (by college) for SAT and MCAT scores are known.

Comment: @rnso I have about 100 colleges and their corresponding data.

Comment: If there is much variation among the types of colleges, that assumption will become less reasonable.  This is because at the upper end the scores may become compressed near their top values.  Another reason to doubt the assumption of constant SD is that some colleges will support a broad range of student capabilities--think open-enrollment institutions--whereas others may have a much more homogeneous pre-med population (think Ivy League schools).

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I understand. I may have a way of obtaining the actual SD's, but I have to check. If we assume homogeneity of variance for the moment, would this regression analysis be proper?

Comment: Although I do not know what you mean by "proper," it is clear that (1) you can compute a regression but (2) you will need to take some care in interpreting the results, because--as you point out in the question--they would not apply to individuals, but only to averages.